# Клик на мобильном устройстве

Tags: javascript

```
function sandwich(clickEl, openEl){
$(document).on('click',clickEl,function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
  if($(openEl).is(":visible")){
      $(openEl).slideUp();
  }else{
    $(openEl).slideDown();
  }

});
}
 sandwich('.main_nav .sandwich_menu','.main_nav ul')
 sandwich('main .sandwich_menu','aside')
```

Данный код обрабатывает клик на компьютере, но не обрабатывает клик на телефоне. Как его адаптировать, чтобы клик отслеживался на телефоне?

Comment: На первый взгляд, все должно работать, добавьте пожалуйста [минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)